# Product measure and probability kernel

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, measure-theory

I have a question regarding this:

> Let $(A,\mathcal{A})$,$(B,\mathcal{B})$ be two $\sigma$-finite measure spaces and $f:A\times B\to \mathbb{R}_+$ be measurable with respect to $\sigma(A,B)$. Let $K$ be a probability kernel on $(A\times B,\sigma(A,B))$ Then the following holds
>   $$\int_{A\times B}f(x,y)(\lambda \otimes K)(\mathrm{d}x,\mathrm{d}y)=\int_{A}\lambda(\mathrm{d}x)\int_{ B}K(x,\mathrm{d}y)f(x,y)$$

Is this a result because the function $f$ is positive hence we can use Fubini-Tonelli?
\begin{align*}
\int_{A\times B}f(x,y)(\lambda \otimes K)(\mathrm{d}x,\mathrm{d}y)=\int_{B}\int_{A}f(x,y)\lambda(\mathrm{d}x) K(x,\mathrm{d}y)=\int_{A}\int_{B}f(x,y)K(x,\mathrm{d}y)\lambda(\mathrm{d}x) 
\end{align*}
Or is this a result because of the $\sigma$-finite measures and $f$ being positive? (or something else?)

Comment: $\sigma$-finiteness and non-negativity of the integrand allows us to apply Tonelli's theorem, yes.